# Refresh an image using UWP and C# (Raspberry Pi3 Windows10 IoT)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm building a simple application that shows an image bitmap using the Image class in UWP.
When i change something on the image, the program won't refresh the image displayed.
I've tried to change source using another temp image but the problem is still the same.
This is the object in the XAML file

```
<Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="128" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ManipulationMode="All"/>
```

This is the code that changes the source of the image

```
private void ChangeImage_BTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        readImage();
    }     


    private void readImage()
    {
        switch (nimg)
        {

            case 1:
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/France.bmp"));
                nimg = 3;
                break;
            case 2:
                //image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Inghilterra.bmp"));
                //nimg = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Area24_128x128.bmp"));
                nimg = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
```

When i switch the image Area_128x128.bmp to France.bmp, I modify the bitmap file adding some draw, switching again to Area_128x128.bmp the image has the old things.
How can i see the image properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "`ms-appx:///`" prefix in the URI refers to the app's install directory. It turns out to be not supported update edits of files at runtime.

For your user case, there are some workarounds you can have a try.

- You can use `ApplicationData.RoamingFolder` like this:

  ```
               Windows.Storage.StorageFolder roamingFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder;
              var file = await roamingFolder.GetFileAsync("France.bmp");
              using (var fileStream = (await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)))
              {
                  var bitImg = new BitmapImage();
                  bitImg.SetSource(fileStream);
                  image.Source = bitImg;
              }
  ```
- You can use `KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary` like this:

  ```
              var file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("France.bmp");
              using (var fileStream = (await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)))
              {
                  var bitImg = new BitmapImage();
                  bitImg.SetSource(fileStream);
                  image.Source = bitImg;
              }
  ```

In general, the path of `KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary` is `C:\Users\[YOUR USER NAME]\Pictures`.

For more information, you can reference [Store and retrieve settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#roaming-data) and [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).